# Trigger Azure devOps pipeline from within a test case

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a devOps pipeline that I want to trigger from within an azure devOps "test case". I was able to associate a unit test to a test case within Visual Studio but can't see a way to associate a devOps pipeline to a test case.

It seems that I would have to load the devOps pipeline inside Visual Studio, test project or similar but can't see a way to do this. It's natural that a pipeline can be called from within an azure devOps test case.

Thanks very much for any answers.

Panos

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the Pipeline from Test case, you can setup the automated test in Azure DevOps. Refer to this doc: [Run automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Here are the key steps of the Automated test settings:

Step1: We need to [associate automated tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops) with test cases in Test Explore. From your description, you have completed this steps.

Step2: Create the Build Pipeline and the Release Pipeline to run the Unit Test.

For example:

Build Pipeline:

[image]

Release Pipeline:

[image]

Step3: Navigate to **Test Plan -> Test Plan settings** to configure the Build and Release Pipeline.

[image]

[image]

Step4: You can run the Release Pipeline in the Test case. Navigate to **Test Plan -> Test suite -> Execute tab -> Run Test**.

**Result:** The Release Pipeline will be triggered.

[image]